# Primitive and modular ideals of $C^{\ast}$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $I$ be a closed subspace of $A$. Then $I$ is called $\textbf{modular}$ if $A/I$ is unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $I$ is called $\textbf{primitive}$ if $I=\operatorname{ker}(\pi) $ for some irreducible representation $\pi$ of $A$. It is known that maximal modular ideal is primitive.

> How does one constructs modular ideals which are not primitive and also the primitive ideals which are not modular?

In $B(\mathcal{H}) $, I could not find any such example. Moreover, in $C_{0}(X) $, I know that modular ideals corresponds to compact subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\cA{\mathcal A}$
$\def\cB{\mathcal B}$
$\def\cC{\mathcal C}$
$\def\cI{\mathcal I}$
$\def\CC{\mathbb C}$
$\def\RR{\mathbb R}$
$\def\h{\mathcal H}$
$\def\k{\mathcal K}$
$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$

You cannot expect to obtain many examples from $\cB(\h)$, since it has a single nontrivial ideal.

Note that you have $A/\ker\pi\simeq\pi(A)$. So you can get non-modular ideals by representing onto non-unital algebras. You can control primitivity by giving a "big" complement to the ideal that cannot have an irrep.

For instance if you take $\cA=\k(\h)$ and $\pi$ the identity representation, you have that $\cA/\ker \pi=\cA$ which is non-unital. And $\pi$ is irreducible. So $\ker\pi$ is primitive but not modular.

To find a modular ideal that is not primitive, we need to start with a unital C$^*$-algebra (so the quotient will be unital) and consider a non-irreducible representation. For example let $\cA=\CC^3$ and $\pi(a,b,c)=a$. Then $\pi(\cA)$ is abelian and two-dimensional, so $\pi$ is not irreducible. That is, the ideal $$I=\ker\pi=\{(0,b,c):\ b,c\in\CC\}$$ is modular but not primitive.

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin!

Comment: Glad I could help :)